# как сделать чтобы при наводке на класс burgerMenu, срабатывало появление класса sectionNav

Tags: css

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ru">
    <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <link  rel="stylesheet" href="uploadFile.css">
       <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <header class="headerBody">
          <nav class="navBody">
             <section class="burgerMenu">
                <div class="spanMenu"></div>
                <div class="spanMenu"></div>
                <div class="spanMenu"></div>
             </section>
    <section class="sectionNav">
       <ul>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
       </ul>
    </section>
          </nav>
       </header>
          <main class="mainBody">
             <article class="articleBody">
                <section class="sectionBody">
                </section>
                   <aside class="asideBody">
                      <section class="sectionUpload">
                         <form action="uploadFile.php" class="form">
                            <label for="file"><p class="fileUpload">Загрузить файл</p></label>
                            <label for="fileUpload"><p class="fileUploadUp">Отправить</p></label>
                               <input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="file" class="file">
                               <input type="submit" name="input" id="fileUpload" class="fileUp">
                         </form>
                      </section>
                   </aside>
             </article>
          </main>
          <footer class="footerBody">
             <section class="sectionFooter">
    
             </section>
          </footer>
    </body>
    </html>

body{background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612142186636-3e65d8a446fe?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80);background-size: cover;}
.headerBody{width: calc(100% - 40px);height: 100px;;border: 1px solid;padding: 10px;margin: 10px;}
.navBody{width: calc(35% - 20px);height: calc(100% - 20px);border: 1px solid;padding: 10px;float: right;}
.mainBody{width: calc(100% - 40px);height: 700px;border: 1px solid;padding: 10px;margin: 10px;}
.articleBody{width: calc(100% - 10px);height: calc(100% - 5px);padding: 5px;}
.sectionBody{width: calc(60% - 15px);height: calc(100% - 10px);border: 1px solid;padding: 5px;float: left;}
.asideBody{width: calc(40% - 15px);height: calc(100% - 10px);border: 1px solid;padding: 5px;float: right;}
.footerBody{width: calc(100% - 40px);height: 100px;border: 1px solid;padding: 10px;margin: 10px;}
.sectionFooter{width: calc(100% - 20px);height: calc(100% - 20px);border: 1px solid;padding: 10px;}

.sectionNav{display:none;}
.burgerMenu{float:right;border: 1px solid;}
.spanMenu{width: 30px;height: 5px;background-color: white;margin: 2px;}
.burgerMenu:hover .spanMenu{width: 30px;height: 5px;background-color: white;margin: 3px;}
.file{display: none;}
.fileUp{display: none;}
```

При :hover - ничего не помогало для появления, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Без js, лишь на чистом css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript

```js
var burgerMenu = document.querySelector('.burgerMenu');
var sectionNav = document.querySelector('.sectionNav');
burgerMenu.onmouseover = function() {
  sectionNav.style.display = 'block';
};
burgerMenu.onmouseout = function() {
  sectionNav.style.display = 'none';
};
```

```css
body {
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612142186636-3e65d8a446fe?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80);
  background-size: cover;
}

.headerBody {
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  height: 100px;
  ;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.navBody {
  width: calc(35% - 20px);
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  float: right;
}

.mainBody {
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  height: 700px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.articleBody {
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  height: calc(100% - 5px);
  padding: 5px;
}

.sectionBody {
  width: calc(60% - 15px);
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
}

.asideBody {
  width: calc(40% - 15px);
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  float: right;
}

.footerBody {
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.sectionFooter {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

.sectionNav {
  display: none;
}

.burgerMenu {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.spanMenu {
  width: 30px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 2px;
}

.burgerMenu:hover .spanMenu {
  width: 30px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 3px;
}

.file {
  display: none;
}

.fileUp {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="headerBody">
  <nav class="navBody">
    <section class="burgerMenu">
      <div class="spanMenu"></div>
      <div class="spanMenu"></div>
      <div class="spanMenu"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="sectionNav">
      <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </nav>
</header>
<main class="mainBody">
  <article class="articleBody">
    <section class="sectionBody">
    </section>
    <aside class="asideBody">
      <section class="sectionUpload">
        <form action="uploadFile.php" class="form">
          <label for="file"><p class="fileUpload">Загрузить файл</p></label>
          <label for="fileUpload"><p class="fileUploadUp">Отправить</p></label>
          <input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="file" class="file">
          <input type="submit" name="input" id="fileUpload" class="fileUp">
        </form>
      </section>
    </aside>
  </article>
</main>
<footer class="footerBody">
  <section class="sectionFooter">

  </section>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
.burgerMenu:hover~.sectionNav {
  display: block;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612142186636-3e65d8a446fe?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80);
  background-size: cover;
}

.headerBody {
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  height: 100px;
  ;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.navBody {
  width: calc(35% - 20px);
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  float: right;
}

.mainBody {
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  height: 700px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.articleBody {
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  height: calc(100% - 5px);
  padding: 5px;
}

.sectionBody {
  width: calc(60% - 15px);
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
}

.asideBody {
  width: calc(40% - 15px);
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  float: right;
}

.footerBody {
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.sectionFooter {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

.sectionNav {
  display: none;
}

.burgerMenu {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.spanMenu {
  width: 30px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 2px;
}

.burgerMenu:hover .spanMenu {
  width: 30px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 3px;
}

.file {
  display: none;
}

.fileUp {
  display: none;
}

.burgerMenu:hover~.sectionNav {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header class="headerBody">
  <nav class="navBody">
    <section class="burgerMenu">
      <div class="spanMenu"></div>
      <div class="spanMenu"></div>
      <div class="spanMenu"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="sectionNav">
      <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </nav>
</header>
<main class="mainBody">
  <article class="articleBody">
    <section class="sectionBody">
    </section>
    <aside class="asideBody">
      <section class="sectionUpload">
        <form action="uploadFile.php" class="form">
          <label for="file"><p class="fileUpload">Загрузить файл</p></label>
          <label for="fileUpload"><p class="fileUploadUp">Отправить</p></label>
          <input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="file" class="file">
          <input type="submit" name="input" id="fileUpload" class="fileUp">
        </form>
      </section>
    </aside>
  </article>
</main>
<footer class="footerBody">
  <section class="sectionFooter">

  </section>
</footer>
```

upd. `X ~ Y` - этот комбинатор находит одноуровневые узлы и идентичен `X + Y`, однако он менее строгий. В то время как смежный селектор (например, `span + p`) выберет только первый элемент, которому непосредственно предшествует шаблонный элемент, этот селектор более общий. В вышеприведенном примере, он будет выбирать любые элементы `p` до тех пор, пока они следуют за `span`.

Comment: к сожалению на учебе запретили использовать js

Comment: спасибо большое, и если не сложно, объясните что такое ~ и как она работает в css, либо просто киньте ссылку.